# Please How do i load contents of my first tab only after reload in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tabs in angular, but i want to load the first tab or default tab only after page refresh, if i click refresh, the first tab details should show automatically and not the second tab. This is my code.

```
        <ngb-tabset [activeId]="activeTab" (tabChange)="activeTab = $event.nextId">
                     <ngb-tab title="My Attendance Log" id="tab1" *ngIf="singleLog" >
                         <ng-template ngbTabContent >

                         </ng-template>
                    </ngb-tab>
                    <ngb-tab  id="tab2" *ngIf="hrDisplay">
                        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>

                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJENw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use activeId here.

For more reference, please refer:
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2461

Comment: please check the code snippet i sent earlier, I already used the activeId binding, but the second tab content shows after some refresh. Thanks